# Jquery ui.draggable - how to get data attribute from a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

HTML allows to put some data into an attribute. In the following example, the key of the data is "myval", the value is 10, the attribute name becomes data-myval :

```
<div id="mydiv" data-myval="10" class="myclass"></div>
```

Jquery getter :

```
var a = $('#mydiv').data('myval');
```

Jquery setter :

```
$('#mydiv').data('myval',20);
```

My question : when i drag and drop this div, i get his class, but i cannot get the data-myval attribute.  All thr var below are undefined :

```
drop : function( event, ui ){
var drag = ui.draggable;
var temp2 = drag.find("div").attr("data-myval");
var temp3 = ui.draggable.attr('data-myval');
var temp4 = ui.draggable.data('myval');
var temp5 = $(ui.draggable).data('myval');
```

Update : i think the cloned node which is dragged, has only class and style attribute, all the other attributes are removed by Jquery.

Any idea ?

Comment: Thought I just had the same issue. This is actually working. For some reason they don't show up in the DOM / object explorer, but when I am doing the same thing, I can check and output the value. To pinpoint your issue, you should definitely create a demo/JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this thing like this:

```
drop : function(event, ui){
    var myval = jQuery(this).data('myval');
}
```

Comment: that's what i did. I updated the post. Thanks for the idea !

Comment: Have you got element in drop callback?

Comment: What is drop callback ?

Comment: It's function that calls when you drop element. You have written it in your question drop : function ...

Comment: Can you make example on jsfiddle?